# Android: Relative layout content goes below screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm new to android and I'm just trying to create a chat client. However the content at the bottom just goes off-screen.

The layout files:

chat_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e1e1e1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#91f1f1f1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/send_button"
        android:text="d" />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.marothiatechs.mchat.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This looks good in preview window of Android Studio. [image: Android Studio Preview]

However, on my device the image button is not visible. [image: Actual device]

But when I increase the "paddingBottom" of linearlayout to say "200dp", the button becomes visible.[image: Actual device - Bottom padding at 200dp]

I found similar questions on SO, and most of them suggest using ScrollView. But I don't think ScrollView is necessary in my case. Any ideas?

Comment: add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"`

Comment: Could you post the entire content of the layout file? Because what you have there seems to be working fine

Comment: Will the person who downvoted my question explain why? I'm facing a real problem when I run the code on my device. On Android Studio, it looks fine.

Comment: @DalmaRacz - This "is" the full layout file. I removed the EditText etc to simplify the problem.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya - To relativelayout or linearlayout

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this-

Use AppBarLayout and ViewPager inside a LinearLayout.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.marothiatechs.mchat.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It works. Could you explain the reason why it worked?

Comment: (I am bad in english, please adjust). CoordinatorLayout  is a parent view and it has 2 childviews (AppBarLayout and ViewPager). you have setting viewpager height as matchparent. so its height will become equal to CoordinatorLayout  height. for eg: CoordinatorLayout height is 500dp, now viewpager height become 500dp, and AppBarLayout height is "x". now total height is (500+x). Thats why image is hidden. Now in updated xml, CoordinatorLayout has only one child(LinearLayout). LinearLoyout has 2 child,so it will get adjust with his parent layout height. I hope you got it...

Comment: Oh. It is so obvious now. Thanks

Comment: It is a great help.

Comment: but `layout_scrollFlags` to `Toolbar` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some logical mistake in implementing a `RelativeLayout`. First, you don't have to set the `orientation` in case of `RelativeLayout`. Second, you don't have to capsulate the whole form inside a `LinearLayout` as you're using `RelativeLayout` you can arrange the views relatively with other views. So here you layout should look like.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e1e1e1">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_face_black_24dp"
        android:text="d" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's your activity_main.xml modified. This is from a working version from my code. Please modify as your need. You may have to change the ids.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Problem persists. I copy pasted your code and the button was still invisible. However, if I add android:paddingBottom="150dp" to ImageButton, the button starts appearing on screen.

Comment: Could the problem be with my activity_main.xml? Posting that file to my original question.