# Android Relative Layout is running off screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a problem in which a relative layout seems to be running off the screen in the emulator but showing properly in the designer.

I have a LinearLayout and a button both inside a RelativeLayout. The LinearLayout contains some TextViews and then a ScrollView with radio buttons (number to be dynamically allocated).

Putting the LinearLayout and the button in the RelativeLayout gets the button to stay at the screen bottom regardless of radio button count. This allows me to anchor the button to the bottom of the screen and the bottom of the LinearLayout to the top of the button.

In the Android Studio designer this works great! The button is at the bottom, and if the radios extend beyond the screen you can scroll them. When I run the emulator though the screen gets cut off before the button! I've tried this in both the Microsoft and Android (so slow) emulators and gotten the same result.

I found a similar question at [Android: Relative layout content goes below screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312444/android-relative-layout-content-goes-below-screen) which pinpointed adding this line to my button:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

That brought it partway back on screen but not all the way, and the rest of that thread is about removing the LinearLayout which I want to keep in this use case. Seems something more is going on here. What am I doing wrong? Here's my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.complexityresolved.lifetracker.RadioInputsActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.complexityresolved.lifetracker.RadioInputsActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/radioInputsActivityDoneButton">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Text With Trait Name"
        android:id="@+id/RadioScreenTextViewTraitName"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Text With Short Description"
        android:id="@+id/RadioScreenTextViewShortDescription"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="pirates"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ninjas"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_irates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="pirates"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_injas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ninjas"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_rates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="pirates"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_njas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ninjas"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="pirates"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_jas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ninjas"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/adio_pirates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="pirates"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/adio_ninjas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ninjas"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/dio_pirates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="pirates"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/dio_ninjas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ninjas"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/raio_pirates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="pirates"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/raio_ninjas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ninjas"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rao_pirates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="pirates"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rao_ninjas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ninjas"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radioInputsActivityDoneButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioInputsActivityDoneButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[Picture in the designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U37gk.jpg)

[Picture in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO384.jpg)

Also, my activity layout as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.complexityresolved.lifetracker.RadioInputsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: no problem found in your layout, can you post a screenshot by enabling layout boundries in developer option ?

Comment: Please share your Activity xml

Comment: If you are using TabbedActivity, then do this, Use AppBarLayout and ViewPager inside a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

I have tested your you, i saw the issue that you mentioned above.
I have updated your code ande posted below. It is working good.

In your Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"      tools:context="com.complexityresolved.lifetracker.RadioInputsActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; I mentioned in my question that I'd already found this article and it had only partially helped. Are you saying I missed something in it? If so, please be more explicit about what I missed; I'm not getting it so far.

Comment: I guess you are using TabbedActivity, am i correct?

Comment: Sorry,I think I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Can you provide output screen shot?

Comment: Screenshots of both the designer and the emulator added.

Comment: I have posted a code. I hope it will fix your problem, but I am not sure, because it is depend on your activity xml.

Comment: I added my activity XML. Working through yours now to try and understand the difference.

Comment: Did you tried, what I have mentioned above? It is not working?

Comment: I have tested your you, I saw the issue that you mentioned above. I have updated your code ande posted here. It is working good. Try this....

Comment: That looks more or less the same as what I tried without any effect. You replicated my problem and the above approach fixed it? I'll try it again with your exact code when I'm by my Dev computer again. I'm assuming the addition of the "$PlaceholderFragment" piece was just for your setup though; if that's not so let me know.

Comment: No, I didn't mention that "$PlaceholderFragment" is my change to fix this issue(ignore that). I have added a LinearLayout inside the CoordinatorLayout. Did you notice that?

Comment: Also i have replicated your problem and this approach fixed it for me.

Comment: Also sorry for this, I have wrongly pasted this line "tools:context="com.complexityresolved.lifetracker.RadioInputsActivity$PlaceholderFragment"" insteadof this " tools:context="com.complexityresolved.lifetracker.RadioInputsActivity"" in my above code(Now I updated that and saved). That makes you confuse. It is my mistake

Comment: That did it! Thank you!!! Not sure why it didn't work when I tried that manually before, but regardless it's fixed now; much appreciated!

Comment: CoordinatorLayout is a parent view and it has 2 childviews (AppBarLayout and ViewPager). you have setting viewpager height as matchparent. so its height will become equal to CoordinatorLayout height. for eg: CoordinatorLayout height is 500dp, now viewpager height become 500dp, and AppBarLayout height is "x". now total height is (500+x). Thats why button is hidden. Now in updated xml, CoordinatorLayout has only one child(LinearLayout). LinearLoyout has 2 child,so it will get adjust with his parent layout height.

Comment: I am not sure, my explaination is correct or not, but I understood like that only...

Comment: Makes sense to me; thanks again for your help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try **weightSum**, Try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.complexityresolved.lifetracker.RadioInputsActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/RadioScreenTextViewTraitName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Text With Trait Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/RadioScreenTextViewShortDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Text With Short Description"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="pirates" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ninjas" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_irates"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="pirates" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_injas"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ninjas" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_rates"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="pirates" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_njas"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ninjas" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_ates"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="pirates" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_jas"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ninjas" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/adio_pirates"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="pirates" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/adio_ninjas"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ninjas" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/dio_pirates"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="pirates" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/dio_ninjas"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ninjas" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/raio_pirates"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="pirates" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/raio_ninjas"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ninjas" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rao_pirates"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="pirates" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rao_ninjas"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ninjas" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.75">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/radioInputsActivityDoneButton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="radioInputsActivityDoneButton" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's an interesting thought; putting the other in a LinearLayout too and weighting. I'm not near my dev computer at the moment but I'll definitely try this when I am. A question in the meantime though; doesn't the weighting approach resize based on screen size? Couldn't that result in the button being oddly large or small on some screens? And more generally, I'm still not sure why the approach I took isn't working so I'm nervous the issue might reappear here.

Comment: yes, it will resize based on screen size but it will be easy to maintain to support all devices having different resolutions.

Comment: How so? If it will resize it seems to me that on certain screens the button will be too small or bizarrely large; is there a way to fix that in your solution?

Comment: because once you given weight you need not to worry about screen size OR you have to make three diffrent layouts for one screen to make it perfect.

Comment: do inform if you are facing any issue @J.Natael

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but I'm still not sure I want this approach. The point to me is that I put a button of a set height at the bottom of the screen and it stays there. Your approach means that button would stretch or shrink with screen differences. My approach shouldn't have that downside except that the button is too low. I think I'm going to try and fix that one issue rather than entirely change the approach I'm taking and introduce other issues in the process. Thank you though!

Comment: Amit; as noted above I appreciate the suggestion but don't think it helps my situation. I'm trying to fix the problem in the approach I've taken and you suggested a completely different approach with a different problem. Instead of doing that I want to solve the problem in the approach I have as I think the problem it has is smaller.

Comment: This is due to different devices you are taking as emulator and designer. you have to create different layout files for that. as shown in link i have posted in comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the this problem by this procedure

**using a relative layout

**first set the boundary items with respect to boundary(left items by using alignparentleft=true and for right items alignparentright=true)

**now set the inner items with respect to both of the right and left items
see my code and screenshot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="11dp"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/memberRankListViewImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fb_profile"
        app:border_color="#FF000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/memberRankListViewText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/memberRankListViewImage"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timeofnotifictioan"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="titlefsdfsdfdfgfhfghfghgfdgjnfdshdshjdfjfghdjlfgdjlfgjldfgnjfgnjfgnhjhfgnjhgnhjkklfdjsdklfjskdfjkfgfgkndfjksdkajsdkasj of job"
        android:textColor="@color/customBlackText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeofnotifictioan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="2015/12/20"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the screenshot

[image: items not overflow example]