# Android: toolbar pushes relative layout down, beyond screen boundary

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I saw questions with similar problems, but when I tried to implement their responses I wasn't able to solve my problem.

Here is a snapshot of my landscape layout:
[image]

As you can see the bottom 'sticks' beyond screen boundary.

And here are my two xml files.

**Activity.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Activities.ScreenActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_screen" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_screen.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/design_navigation_elevation"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Activities.ScreenActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_screen"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="That&apos;s it! Press the button to use your gadget!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\u2714"
        android:id="@+id/closeAppButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_round"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textSize="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#06BF60"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sometimes Preview tool shows view components incorrect. Did you get to run your app? Place some view at bottom and she do you get it right or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` property if you will remove this then layout will stick on Toolbar.

To avoid this you need to set the static height to relative layout or wrapcontent!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the coordinator layout in activity_main.xml is having 2 children - the AppBarLayout and the included content_screen.xml. The AppBarLayout has its layout_height property set to wrap_content as usual but the problem is **the layout_height property of the content_screen.xml which is set to match_parent**. Now since it is a child of activity_main, content_screen gets its height from activity_main which causes it to overflow.

A solution to this would be to create a child of CoordinatorLayout in activity_main.xml and wrap AppbarLayout and content_screen in it as proposed in this similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330078/android-relative-layout-is-running-off-screen).

There may be better way but I think this should solve your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Activities.ScreenActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_screen" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```