# Unable to view the bottom items in the android scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'am having a layout with `ScrollView`. I'am unable to view all the items as soon as my layout is opened
I'am unable to scroll down complete but after editing something in `EditText` and if I again scroll I'am able to view all the items.
Please help in solving this issue.

Below is my layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"


    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Diabetes Risk Assesment"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#00abea"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_diabetesage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_diabetes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="@string/hint_age"

                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Gender"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/diaradiogroup">

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Male"
                    android:id="@+id/rmale"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Female"
                    android:id="@+id/rfemale"/>
            </RadioGroup>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_diabeteswaist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="30dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_waist"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_waist"

                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/strexercise"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/diaexxercise">

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Yes"
                    android:id="@+id/remale"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="No"
                    android:id="@+id/refemale"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/strexercisedaily"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/exercisedaily">

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Yes"
                    android:id="@+id/redmale"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="No"
                    android:id="@+id/redfemale"/>
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/strparents"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spingender"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
           >



        </LinearLayout>-->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: there are 2 `EditText` in your code, which you mentioned?

Comment: clicking in both the edit box and typing something when comes back i'am able to scroll completely

Comment: Are you using this layout inside the TabLayout?

Comment: yes inside the tablayout any help please

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312444/android-relative-layout-content-goes-below-screen/35331698#35331698)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because your `EditText` is being focused by default.

You can remove that by adding this line in your `onCreate()` in your activity.

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

After hours of search i founnd a solution for my problem.

add this attribute in scrollview -- app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

and remove the same attribute from the  ViewPager

So the layout ScrollView should be below

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:fillViewport="true">
```

and ViewPager should be like this

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```